# UIButton handling in array

Tags: iphone, button, touch, selector

I created array of buttons, but i am not see, that buttons handles touch events ( buttonEvent: not calls)

This my code - is it not correct ?

```
- (void)loadView{
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
[backgroundImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
backgroundImageView.opaque = YES;
self.view = backgroundImageView;
[backgroundImageView release];

CGRect brandRect = CGRectMake(90, 25, 140, 70);
UIImageView *brandImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:brandRect];
[brandImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"brand.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:brandImageView];
buttons = [NSMutableArray array];

int y = 100;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++ ){
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(20, y, 280, 50)];
    if ( i == 0 ){
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select_passive.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Object%d",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
    button.tag = 1000 + i ;
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    y += 60;
}

-(void)buttonEvent:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"new button clicked!!!");
}
```

Comment: I found solution  -  backgroundImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES  solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding buttons to uiimageview, which has interaction disabled.

Also, you don't have an array of buttons, because buttons is autoreleased, and you never add object into buttons array.